# How to show a Toast message in a Fragment using MVVM model

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm, android-toast

I am trying to show a Toast message in a Fragment using MutableLiveData Event, but I cannot show the toast message, error is

`None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied. makeText(Context!, CharSequence!, Int) defined in android.widget.Toast makeText(Context!, Int, Int) defined in android.widget.Toast`

ViewModel

```
class AddProductViewModel (
    private val repository: ProductRepository,
    private val context: Context
): ViewModel(), Observable {

    private  val statusMessage = MutableLiveData<Event<String>>()

    val message : LiveData<Event<String>>
        get() = statusMessage

}
```

Fragment

```
class AddProductFragment: Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: AddProductBinding
    private lateinit var addProductViewModel: AddProductViewModel
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding =  DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.add_product, container, false)
        val dao = SubscriberDatabase.getInstance(requireActivity().applicationContext).productDAO
        val repository = ProductRepository(dao)
        val factory = AddProductViewModelFactory(repository, requireActivity().applicationContext)
        addProductViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(AddProductViewModel::class.java)
        binding.addProductViewModel = addProductViewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        val view = binding.root

        addProductViewModel.message.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            it.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let {
                ***Error is on this line***
                Toast.makeText(viewLifecycleOwner,it, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show
            }
        })

        return view
    }
}
```

How can I correct this please thanks in advance

Thanks
R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use next line for showing a `Toast` message in a `Fragment`:

```
 Toast.makeText(context, it, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

You use `viewLifecycleOwner` as the first argument but it should be a `Context`.